# extract specific bytes from string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying o write a simple client - server app in java where in I pass messages form 1 machine to other. The message pattern is source address(1st 12 bytes), desti address(next 12 bytes), message type(next 2 bytes)

I get 1 string as input and now I need to separate these fields. I tried using getBytes and to char array but they do not give excepted result.

Is there any other way to do it?

`char separatedString[] = inputString.toCharArray();
    char messageType = separatedString[12];
    String returnString=null;
    switch(messageType){
    do something
    }`

I am taking 12th char because assuming that 1st 0-11 chars will be for source and destination.but if I get inputString as "192.168.14.14...." for example I am getting 4 as message type which is wrong. this is entirely source address.

Thanks

Comment: Post the Code you are having trouble with ! Also Example of InputString your are receiving

Comment: If your inputString is  "192.168.14.14...." it appears to me that the expectation that the first 12 bytes are the source address is simply not met: you should check the specifications of the input again.

Comment: give example of what your *input looks like exactly* and what your *desired output looks like exactly*